# How do I set up a localhost website?

Tags: permissions, apache2, chromium, php, lamp

I have created a simple index.php file which I have places in `/var/www/` next I changed the permissions of the file with `sudo chmod +x index.php`

I then ran Chromium and typed in **localhost** to the address bar. Chromium then reports that it's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down or your network may not be properly configured.

I have a strong feeling that I have not configured something (or anything) as it should be configured.

*I have searched through a number of posts before adding this question and could not find the answer.*

Can someone point me in the right direction please

do I need to install LAMP?

## Update 1

the following lines appear in my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   simon
```

Comment: Have you installed apache2? If not, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to install Apache 2 and PHP (since you are using index.php)

```
sudo apt-get install php5 apache2
```

That will install both apache2 and PHP

That should work after you installed it. Also, you don't need to make index.php executable. It just needs to be readable.

Comment: I am currently installing as suggested, to remove the executable permission, do I need to enter `chmod -x index.php` ?

Comment: Yes. It should remove the executable permission.

Comment: I answered that question by trying it :) Thank you so much for your help. It's not easy being a novice, but I'm learning!

Comment: That's good to know. Keep learning and applying what you learn :)